# display image a text inline with each other

Tags: css

i have this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#box {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.box-inner {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#text, #text a {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#F36F25;
    margin:10px;
}
#text:hover, #text a:hover {
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#text img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right:20px;
}
</style>
```

its currently displaying the image and text inline but i have multiple images/text below each other. how can i make all the images align in the same position below each other?

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8dsTu/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8dsTu/4/

```
<div id="text">
    <img src="../images/icons/address.png" height="60" />
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Address 1,<br />
        Address 2,<br />
        County Post Code
    </div>
 </div>
```

Edit css:

```
.box-inner {
     width:80%;
     margin:0 auto 0 auto;
     text-align:left;
     margin-left:100px;
}
```

Comment: thats what im looking for :) just a quick question, whats the best way to make these display all inline now but as the page gets smaller to make them like your above jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dsTu/7/      :D You use attribute "align" in <img />                  and edit "vertical-align: middle;" in css: **#text img**

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, `id` property is meant to be unique and you have a few `<div>` elements with `id="text"`. To get what you want you'll have to: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dsTu/5/))

1. replace all `id="text"` with `class="text"` and add `<div class="caption">` to wrap each of the captions:

   ```
   <div id="box">
       <div class="box-inner">
           <div class="text">
               <img src="../images/icons/telephone.png" height="60" />
               <div class="caption">00000 00 00 00</div>
           </div>
           <div class="text">
               <img src="../images/icons/email.png" height="60" />
               <div class="caption">sales@domain.co.uk</div>
           </div>
           <div class="text">
               <img src="../images/icons/address.png" height="60" />
               <div class="caption">Address 1,<br />Address 2,<br />County Post Code</div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Adjust the css:

```css
    #box {
        width:100%;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#eeeeee;
    }

    .box-inner {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .text, .text a {
        font-size:16px;
        color:#F36F25;
        margin:10px;
    }

    .text:hover, .text a:hover {
        color:#666666;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .text img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right:20px;
    }

    .caption{ /* This is the new bit - display:inline-block does the trick. adjust margin-top to your needs */
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-top:15px;
    }
```

Comment: i dont want them side by side. i just want the image and text side by side and then the next one below the first one and so on but the images to be in line going down...

Comment: the jsFiddle is fine, i just need a way to get the images on the left inline with each other going down

Comment: @charliejsford the problem is only with the address?

Comment: i will create an image... 1 second

Comment: @charliejsford check the new answer and fiddle

Comment: the images arent inline?

Comment: @charliejsford you can leave them `inline` there will be no difference.. just easier for me to understand because an image has by default the shape of a block not of inline..

Answer (score 0):

```
#box {
width:100%;
background-color:#eeeeee;
```

}

```
.box-inner {
width:80%;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
text-align:center;
```

}

```
.text, .text a {
font-size:16px;
color:#F36F25;
```

}

```
.text:hover, .text a:hover {
color:#666666;
text-decoration:none;
```

}

```
.text img {
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right:20px;
width: 60px;
background: black;
float: left;
```

}

```
.text {
overflow: hidden;
width: 250px;
margin: 10px auto;
```

}

Something like this? But you must replace your id's with classes.